# error strlen not a member of std only on linux not on solaris

Tags: c++

below code compiles on Solaris using Sun Studio but on linux using gcc it says strlen is not a member of std.

```
inline std::string pathname(char const *p)
{
    std::string pname;
    std::transform(p, p+std::strlen(p), std::back_inserter(pname), platform::switch_slash);
    return pname;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: And you include `<cstring>` and not `<string.h>`?

Comment: What are your `#include` directives? And what version of Solaris, Linux and GCC are you using?

Comment: For what it is worth I am porting code from Windows to Linux and I ran into the same thing.  juanchopanza was right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include the `cstring` header to get `std::strlen`:

```
#include <cstring>
```